# Where do I place OnItemClickListener?

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener

I have built a test app that shows few records on a listview.

Now I want to click on an item and see the info on the debug of android studio.

I know I'm supposed to create an OnItemClickListener but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to place it.

I tried placing it on the mainactivity, the app works, but the click function is never called, so there is something wrong.

I looked around Google for some help, but I couldn't wrap my mind around it.

It should be a straightforward action (I have a list, I click an item) but I am not able to make it work.

This what I tried so far:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDemo);
        List list = new LinkedList();

        list.add(new Contatto("Antonio","Rossi","1234567890"));
        list.add(new Contatto("Pino","Bianchi","2345678901"));
        list.add(new Contatto("Peppe","Verdi","3456789012"));
        list.add(new Contatto("Leo","Rossi","4567890123"));
        list.add(new Contatto("Mario","Blu","5678901234"));
        list.add(new Contatto("Aldo","Da Vinci","6789012345"));

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.rowcustom,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        OnItemClickListener clickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Contatto c = (Contatto)adapter.getItem(position);
                Log.d(c.getNome(),c.getTelefono());
            }
        };
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);
    }
}
```

OnItemClickListener is not recognized, and getItem neither.

The autocorrect of android Studio proposes me to change to "AdapterView.OnItemClickListener", getItem has nooptions to be recognized.

I tried to add " implements OnItemClickListener" on the class declaration, but it doesn't work either (gives error, name is in red, no solutions are provided by the android studio).

At one point I was able to remove all errors, but the code still didn't work and I don't remember what I did, I was just fiddling.

Comment: Searching for "click listview android" show multiple answers on SO, none of those help?
If not, you should post your code so people have something to review that will help answer your questions without guessing at multiple potential problems.

Comment: @dominicoder I've added code and further explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can put the OnClickListener in onCreate()

If you post your code, that would certainly help

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that are questionable about the code you posted.

1. You create `OnItemClickListener` but you don't have an import for `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. So are you sure you're using the right class?
2. Inside your `onItemClick`, you reference `adapter`, which is the local parameter of type `AdapterView<?>`, but `AdapterView` has no such method `getItem(int)`. It can't be a reference to your `CustomAdapter` because that's not declared `final`.
3. Your use of `Log.d(c.getNome(),c.getTelefono());` is wrong. The various log methods take a "tag" as the first parameter. It could be that you're not seeing the log messages because that's just wrong.

So, really, this shouldn't even compile. Please review your code and post the most recent, most correct, most compilable version you have. Including the code for you custom adapter and layout wouldn't hurt either.

Have you tried using your debugger to step through this code and seeing if a breakpoint at the click point gets hit?

Comment: While fiddling with the code I had at some point a version that did compile but didn't work. I tried to replicate that but the code I posted so far is what I was able to recall until now. I will post all the other classes and the xml to provide a better view to the issues